# App Engine PostgreSQL connection error using TCP

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Python 3 application deployed in Google App Engine, flexible environment.

I'm using psycopg2 to connect to a PostgreSQL instance hosted in Google cloud SQL.

I'm having trouble connecting to PostgreSQL from Google App Engine.

Cloud SQL Proxy seems to initialize ok, but it binds to `0.0.0.0`

`Listening on 0.0.0.0:5432 for projectID:us-central1:my-db`

Trying to connect on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` doesn't work. Connection is refused.

What does work is using the docker (app engine flexible environment uses docker underneath) default IP `172.17.0.1` (from the docker0 adapter)

Using that IP address to connect to Cloud SQL seems like it would bite me in the ass if someone decides to change it.

Why is this happening?

Is using the default docker0 adapter's IP address a viable long term solution?

Is there an alternative other than switching to a `socket` based connection instead of the `tcp` approach.

Comment: Check this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55165610/8963486) explains about 127.17.0.1 default IP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've switched from using TCP as the connection method and to using a Unix Socket.

The TCP issue seems to be a bug in the app engine flexible environment. But it's a beta feature (it is under the name beta_settings in app.yaml) and I'm not holding out for Google to fix it.

I also don't want to commit to an IP address that could be changed sometime in the future as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are running the Cloud SQL proxy on your host machine, while you are attempting to run your application from inside a container. The reason it can't connect to the proxy is because `127.0.0.1` refers to docker's loopback interface, while the proxy is bound to the host machine's interface. The `172.17.0.1` is the address the container can use to can reach the host interface.

One alternative is to [use host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) (`https://docs.docker.com/network/host/`), by passing in `--network host`. This will cause the host's interface to be used for the application.

Comment: Unfortunately this is on Google App Engine I don't think I can change the networking via the Dockerfile.

Comment: This is how you can accomplish this when running locally - when running in App Engine Flex the enviroment provides the port on `127.0.0.1` for you. See the [Connecting from App Engine page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_the_flexible_environment_to).

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior on App Engine Flex environment. I followed the same docs, but it seems to be a bug in App Engine

Comment: In your original comment, you mentioned that you are using the proxy. Are you attempting to run the proxy inside the App Engine environment?

Comment: That's how google app engine connects to cloud sql. Via cloud sql proxy, at least on flexible environment.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are just updating the `app.yaml` and then connecting to the TCP socket on `127.0.0.1:5432`? That works every time for me.

Comment: that's what I was doing. But it doens't work for some reason. I switched to the unix socket method.

Comment: If you feel that you experiencing an issue, you can create a case [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491299&template=1161102) which is under a private component and you can also provide your project-id in order to investigate deeper your issue.